# Configuring proxy for Allure +Gradle+jUnit4 while using allure plugin for gradle

Tags: java, gradle, junit, proxy, allure

Is there a way to build reports with Allure while using a proxy and building project with Gradle?

So far i've seen only solutions for Maven (you just specify proxy settings in settings.xml) but couldn't find any solution for Gradle.

I use allure plugin for Gradle, tests written for jUnit4.

My proxy configuration is stored in gradle.properties and works for everything except Allure. Allure does put its json files with test results in its "allure-results" folder, but folder allure-reports is empty.

I can't run a task "allureReport" either:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':downloadAllure'.
>
> java.io.IOException: Unable to tunnel through proxy. Proxy returns "HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authentication Required"

Couldn't find a solution so far.
I'm relatively new to automated testing.
My build.gradle looks like

```
apply plugin: 'java'

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath "io.qameta.allure:allure-gradle:2.5"
}
}

apply plugin: 'io.qameta.allure'

allure {
aspectjweaver = true
autoconfigure = true
version = '2.5.0'

resultsDir = file('.../allure-results')
reportDir = file('.../allure-reports')
useJUnit4 {
    version = '2.0-BETA10'
}
clean true
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }

configurations {
agent
}

dependencies {
...
agent "org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.13"
compile "ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-junit-adaptor:1.5.4"

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
            testCompile 'com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk:3.2.0'
...
}
```

Comment: create an issue here https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-gradle/issues

Comment: @DmitryBaev I ran downloadAllure with --debug option and found out that for some reason couldn put .zip file into a a /build folder through my proxy. Did it manually and now report generation finishes without any problems.